# How close Bootstrap datepicker when it is in viewMode: year?

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I need to close datepicker when user finally select full date. This mean that user first select year, then month and after that date, but after last action datepicker remain open. How can I make this close on last user action?
I'm not sure is any code needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will probably work:

```
$('yourpickerid').on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

Update:

Try these 2 different options:

```
$('#dp2').on('changeDate', function (ev) {
   //close when viewMode='0' (days)
   if(ev.viewMode === 'days'){
      $('#dp2').datepicker('hide');
   }
})
```

or

```
$("#date").datepicker({
    autoclose: true
});
```

Comment: This will fire immediately after first user click (year selected). But I need close when all parts of date selected.

Comment: No, this is plugin option, I'm not setting this on my side.